# Show username or login button depending on state

Tags: jquery

Working against jQuery 1.3.2 I'm looking for best practices that implement the typical '*You are logged in as:*' or '*Click here to login*' pattern.

thx

Comment: Typically the authentication state is something that is determined server-side. As such, I don't see how jQuery is relevant to the question? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looking for the UI aspect only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<script>
    var logged = '{$usernameFromServer}';
    $(document.ready(function () {
        var span = null;
        if (logged != '') {
            span = $('<span>You are logged in as: ' + logged + '</span>');
        } else {
            span = $('<span>Click here to log in</span>');
        }

        $('#someDiv').append(span.html());
    });
</script>
```

for a quick & dirty solution, to give you some idea, I coded that directly into SO so no guarantees :)

Comment: Thankx...i can make that work but i'm kinda looking for a broader discussion (links) so I can be confident I'm applying a mature pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a "pattern" here much less a mature one.

Patterns are a quick way to reference a typical implementation style or solution to a problem. They are generic in nature, and are not typically used in reference to user interface elements.

One the client side there is plenty of discussion around the design aspects of [login boxes](http://www.smileycat.com/design_elements/login_forms/), but rarely implementation, because this is really dependent on how you have implemented login and session management.